# How to open gem library using with vim and console using oneliner command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sh, vi

Is there a way how to combine this two commands into the one in a console ?

---

Run `1st command` and use `vi` for the output from the `first command` as oneliner.

---

1.

```
bundle show activerecord

#=> /home/jusepe/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14
```

2.

```
vi /home/jusepe/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: Using a subshell**

This is the easiest solution

```
vi $(bundle show activerecord)
```

Or

```
vi `bundle show activerecord`
```

**Option 2: Using xargs**

This is the slightly more 'bashy' way of doing things but for such a simple case, its probably overkill.

```
bundle show activerecord | xargs vim
```